# if $\sin(p)=\frac{8}{17}$, $\cos(p)=\frac{15}{17}$, $\sin(q)=\frac 35$, and $\cos(q)=\frac 45$, find $\cos(p-q)$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin(p)=\frac{8}{17}$, $\cos(p)=\frac{15}{17}$, $\sin(q)=\frac 35$, and $\cos(q)=\frac 45$, find $\cos(p-q)$Please help me solve the trigonometry problem described above.

Answer (score 8):

Just apply the relationship $\cos(p-q)=\cos(p)\cos(q)+\sin(p)\sin(q)$.

Comment: elaborate please

Comment: @TomAlley There is nothing else to elaborate on; you use the above formula and substitute in the values.

Comment: Plugged in values and don't get right answer. What do you get when you plug them in.

Comment: Show your work. Without that, we can't help you any further.